# Blocks that look quartz

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What blocks in Minecraft look as close as possible to quartz? Or are there any methods like shaders that make other blocks look like quartz?

Comment: One way would be to just "cheat" the blocks you need. Or if you want it less cheating you could throw away your stacks of stone and give yourself an equal amount of quartz, after all this is a free sandbox game.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're looking for blocks which are similar in appearance, try **white wool**, **snow blocks**, **clay blocks**, or **iron blocks**. As for biomes, I think the only thing that they affect (colour wise) are leaf blocks, grass blocks and trees.

If you're on PC you could install a **custom texture pack**. Or you could even **copy the texture for quartz and paste it onto another block**. For example, if you pasted it over the texture for sand, then lakes and oceans in your game would look like they were surrounded by quartz blocks. But remember, **the block you pasted the texture over would still retain its original properties**, so if you picked sand, it would be affected by gravity, it would be breakable by hand and it would make crunching sounds when stepped on. Smooth stone would offer the right properties and footstep sounds, but on the flip side you'd see quartz in place of smooth stone when you dug down/started mining.

Comment: Could Chisled Sandstone work?

Comment: You're the builder, it's up to you to decide what block you would like to use. It would 'work' in as much as it has the right sort of properties, but it might be a little too yellow if you're wanting to build 'The White House'.

Comment: I'm asking if that block could be used as the replacement for the quartz texture.

Comment: Very sorry, I misunderstood! Yes, that should be fine. It's not affected by gravity and it should sound the same when walked on.